# Send an email via Mailgun with Python httplib library

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests, mailgun, httplib

Following the Mailgun tutorial I am able to send an email with the requests library in Python via Mailgun.

I need to use "httplib" (not requests!) in Python to send emails. However,the Mailgun tutorial does not provide any example of how to use httplib.

```
# this is a "requests" example from the Mailgun tutorial
requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/" + env.MG_SANDBOX_DOMAIN_NAME + "/messages",
    auth=("api", env.MG_KEY),
    files=[("attachment", open(my_PDF_full_path))],
    data={
        "from": "myemail@domain.com",
        "to": "youremail@domain.com",
        "subject": "TESTING EMAIL",
        "text": "TESTING EMAIL",
        "html": "<p>TESTING EMAIL</p"
    }
)
```

How can I convert this example to codes that use the "httplib" library in Python?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me.

```
import httplib
import base64
import urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({
    'from': 'from@someone.com',
    'to': 'to@someone.com',
    'subject': 'This is a test',        
    'text': 'Hello\nThis is a test message.'
})

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic {0}'.format(base64.b64encode("api:key-myapikey")),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.mailgun.net", 443)
conn.request('POST', '/v3/my-sandbox.mailgun.org/messages', params, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()   
print response.status, response.reason  
data = response.read()  
print data
conn.close()
```

If you need to send attachments then it requires a bit more work.

Comment: hi @Isaac, i will update with code examples when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to send emails with Python3, no external libs required.

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def send_mg_mail(account='', key='', addr_to='', m_subject='', m_text=''):
    mg_url = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{0}.mailgun.org/messages'.format(account)
    addr_from = "user <user@{0}.mailgun.org>".format(account)
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"from": addr_from, "to": addr_to, "subject": m_subject, "text":m_text})
    data = data.encode('ascii')
    auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    auth_handler.add_password(user="api", realm='MG API', passwd=key, uri=mg_url)
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    d = urllib.request.urlopen(mg_url, data)
    ret_code = str(d.code) + " " + d.reason
    print(ret_code)
```

key is in the format:

```
key-<numbers>
```

Check your mailgun account to get the "account" string, might be something like:

```
sandbox123456789abcdefgh...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this issue, I used the multipart_encode and MultipartParam lib

```
load = {
    "from": messages['from'],
    "to": messages['to'],
    "subject": messages['subject'],
    "text": messages['text'],
    "attachment": MultipartParam(
        "attachment",
        filename=messages['filename'],
        filetype='application/pdf',
        value=messages['attachment'])
}

payload, hd = multipart_encode(load)

hd['Authorization'] = 'Basic %s' % (base64.b64encode(api),)

resp = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, payload="".join(payload), method='POST', headers=hd, validate_certificate=True)
```